# Send or edit Firebase Data from Saleforce

Tags: firebase, post, salesforce, apex

I m willing to to edit a data from a collection in Google Firebase using Apex language of Saleforce.

That means for example, that i have Employee collection in Google Firebase, and Employee Table in Salesforce.

If we add a new employee or edit an employee in Saleforce, i want to perform the same change in Firebase.
Does any one has an idea of how can this be made?

I ve already done something like that for the communication from Firebase to Saleforce by using a REST Call to the Json File in which the firebase is storing the data collection and retrieve those data.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the [Firebase REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database)?

Comment: Hi @Dharmaraj, yes i checked it, and i m already able to access the json file where are ma data stored. Now I m trying to find a way to use the PATCH and POST functions

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option available - especially with unsupported formats is a Cloud Function onRequest call. This allows you to invoke cloud functions to make administrative changes to your backend for ALL services. You will need to handle some sort of validation request or secret password that only your services know to prevent abuse should that port be discovered.

A simple onRequest function: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#modify-name

How to Invoke: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#invoke_an_http_function

If your server/API has the availability to log in through the REST API, this would be more ideal, allowing you to secure access for these writes based on a role or user UID and performing the necessary functions without exposing your server directly.

Comment: Hello  @DIGI, i already have access to the json file which contains the data. I guess I m able to edit it with a POST or PATCH request, the thing now is how to access to one specific element of the complex tree in order to change it ...

Comment: you can specify the field with an update or set:merge to the field, if it's nested within an object map, you can use dot notation to update nested fields